# How to convert a matrix into a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data which is basically a matrix but is in data.table format:

Lets call this matA:

```
Date    compA compB compC 
200101      1     2     3 
200102      2     4     1
```

How do I make the matrix into a database type in data.table?

Lets call this dataset dtB:

```
Date    Company    Data
200101    compA       1
200101    compB       2
200101    compC       3
200102    compA       2
200102    compB       4
200102    compC       1
```

I have thought about a very stupid way to make a list of companies:

```
comp= as.data.table(c("compA", "compB", "compC"))
date= as.data.table(rep(matA[1,1],3))
data= as.data.table(matA[1,])

dtb= date[,Company := comp]
dtb= dtb[, Data := data]
```

And obviously I can at most get the data in date 200101. To get 200102, I write a for loop. Then, merge both 200101 and 200102 into dtB according to the colnames.

Is there a clever way to do this in data.table?
Many thanks

Comment: How do you guys seems to remember all the functions?? I am always trial and error... That works btw

Comment: Many thanks by the way! More trial and error!

Comment: I think we're all in trial and error phase.  Some of us have just spent so much time on the error side that we are starting to get faster at moving to the trial side. :)

Comment: It also helps to search for the right terms on google/SO. For example, this would be a "reshape from wide to long format" type of question, which would give you SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

Comment: Yes the problem is I constantly on stackoverflow, but it always hard to search what you need with the right term!

Comment: The data.table package has a `melt` command as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a true matrix, as in:

```
matA <- 
  as.matrix(
    read.table(text=
      "Date    compA compB compC 
      200101      1     2     3 
      200102      2     4     1",
      header=TRUE,
      row.names=1)
  )
names(dimnames(matA)) <- c('Date','Company')
matA
#        Company
#  Date   compA compB compC
#  200101     1     2     3
#  200102     2     4     1
```

...then you can use the base `as.data.frame( as.table(x) )`.

```
as.data.frame(
  as.table(matA),
  responseName = 'Data'
)

#     Date Company Data
# 1 200101   compA    1
# 2 200102   compA    2
# 3 200101   compB    2
# 4 200102   compB    4
# 5 200101   compC    3
# 6 200102   compC    1
```

No dependencies required.

This takes advantage of `as.data.frame()` method for the `table` class:

> The `as.data.frame` method for objects inheriting from class `"table"` can
>   be used to convert the array-based representation of a contingency
>   table to a data frame containing the classifying factors and the
>   corresponding entries (the latter as component named by `responseName`).
>   This is the inverse of `xtabs`.

Of course, if you want, you can do `as.data.table( as.table(x) )`, or do a `melt`.

Answer (score 2):

**Base R**

```
data.frame(Date = matA[,"Date"],
           Company = rep(colnames(matA)[-1], each = NROW(matA)),
           Data = as.vector(matA[,-1]))
#    Date Company Data
#1 200101   compA    1
#2 200102   compA    2
#3 200101   compB    2
#4 200102   compB    4
#5 200101   compC    3
#6 200102   compC    1
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
melt(data = as.data.table(matA),
     id.vars = "Date",
     variable.name = "Company",
     value.name = "Data")
#     Date Company Data
#1: 200101   compA    1
#2: 200102   compA    2
#3: 200101   compB    2
#4: 200102   compB    4
#5: 200101   compC    3
#6: 200102   compC    1
```

**DATA**

```
matA = structure(c(200101L, 200102L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Date", "compA", "compB", "compC")))
```